# how can I insert a row in my database from 'adb shell'

Tags: android, sqlite

I can connect to my android database using 'sqlite3' command. So I get a 'sqlite' prompt, like this:

And I create a table like this:

```
sqlite> .schema
CREATE TABLE table1 (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, test1 TEXT);
```

My question: how can I use sqlite command to insert a row in that table?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes if you are able to create table then it is simple to add row in that table.
use below line in your sqlite command prompt.

```
INSERT INTO table1 values(1,'Name1','test1');
INSERT INTO table1 values(2,'Name2','test2');
```

Now if you want to check if the values are inserted in database or not use

```
SELECT * FROM table1;
```

and you are done.